# Как создать круговое меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, svg, анимация

Меня заинтересовала работа участника [@UModeL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265406/umodel), где он нарисовал круговое меню с использованием технологии CSS.

Вот его [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1254179/377637) на вопрос [Как сделать треугольник с закругленной линией (не углом)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1254123/377637):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vw; max-height: 90vh;
  width: 90vh; max-width: 90vw;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px violet;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 50%; width: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewy(30deg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0px violet;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, black, blue);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.8s ease-out;
}
li:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(60deg) skewy(30deg); }
li:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(120deg) skewy(30deg); }
li:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(180deg) skewy(30deg); }
li:nth-child(5) { transform: rotate(240deg) skewy(30deg); }
li:nth-child(6) { transform: rotate(300deg) skewy(30deg); }

ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0px violet;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
li:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 10px violet;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

li a {
  margin: 20% 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 33%; width: 33%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: bold 100%/1em sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: skewy(-30deg) rotate(0deg);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px violet;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
li:nth-child(2) a { transform: skewy(-30deg) rotate(-60deg); }
li:nth-child(3) a { transform: skewy(-30deg) rotate(-120deg); }
li:nth-child(4) a { transform: skewy(-30deg) rotate(-180deg); }
li:nth-child(5) a { transform: skewy(-30deg) rotate(-240deg); }
li:nth-child(6) a { transform: skewy(-30deg) rotate(-300deg); }

li:hover a {
  color: violet; box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Автор: [@UModeL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265406/umodel)

**Вопрос:** возможно ли нечто подобное воспроизвести, используя любые другие средства и технологии для рисования и создания такого эффекта анимации, указанные в метках вопроса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил сделать круговое меню немного функциональным с привязкой к нашему сайту - [***stackoverflow***](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions)

- Всплывающие подсказки:

`<title> Все вопросы [javascript]  </title>`

- Круг разбит на сектора, для каждого сектора свой `path`, чтобы была
  возможность привязать отдельную ссылки к своему сектору и соответствующей подсказке.
- При наведении курсора сектор подцвечивается
- Тень реализуется с помощью SVG фильтра
- Все ссылки рабочие в пределах сайта, пощелкайте ради интереса
- Цвета заданы с помощью CSS переменных, для более легкой смены
  цветовой темы по своему вкусу

*Для более глубокого проникновения в работу приложения можно почитать комментарии к коду*

```css
svg {
  height: 330px;
  width: 330px;
  --d:gold;
  --r:greenYellow;
  --g:yellowgreen;
}

#spot {
  fill:white;
  pointer-events:none;
  }
 #arrow {
 fill:none;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2;
 pointer-events:none;
 } 

#center {
fill:#FF4500;
stroke:white;
stroke-width:3;
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;

} 
#center:hover {
fill: var(--g);
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}

#s1,#s3, #s5, #s7 {
fill:#797979;
cursor: pointer; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#s2,#s4,#s6,#s8 {
fill:#FF4500;    
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}


#s1:hover, #s3:hover, #s5:hover, #s7:hover  {
 fill: var(--d);
 filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
#s2:hover, #s4:hover, #s6:hover, #s8:hover  {
 fill: var(--r);
 filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox='0 0 110 110'> 
    <defs>  
     <!-- Фильтр тени при наведении -->
<filter id="drop-shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" height="130%" width="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
      <feOffset dx="1" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs> 
  <!-- Сегменты круга с рабочими ссылками -->
<g transform="rotate(-22.5 55 55)" >
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions"> 
    <title> Все вопросы </title>
  <path id="s1"  d="M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 90.35 Z"/>
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [javascript]  </title>
      <path id="s2"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 90.35 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 105 Z"/>
     </a> 
    
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
    <title> Все вопросы [SVG]  </title>
<path id="s3"  d="M 55 55 L 55 105 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.6447 90.35 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css"> 
       <title> Все вопросы [CSS]  </title>
    <path id="s4"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 90.353 A 50 50 0 0 1 5 55 Z" />
    </a>
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java"> 
     <title> Все вопросы [java] </title>
<path id="s5"  d="M 55 55 L 5 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.64 19.64 Z" />
</a> 
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">
       <title> Все вопросы python  </title>
    <path id="s6"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 5 Z" />
    </a> 
<a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help"> 
     <title> Справочный центр </title> 
<path id="s7"  d="M 55 55 L 55 5 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 19.64 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [php]   </title>
    <path id="s8"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 105 55 Z" />
    
    </a>
</g>  
      <a xlink:href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html"> 
        <title> Все вопросы [HTML]  </title> 
     
  <circle id="center" cx='55' cy='55' r='17'  />  
    <text x="45" y="57" fill="white" font-size="8px" pointer-events="none">HTML</text>
  </a>
     <text  x="69" y="30" fill="white" font-size="10px" pointer-events="none">[Php]</text> 
       <text  x="45" y="20" fill="white" font-size="10px" pointer-events="none">Help</text>  
         <text transform="translate(-45 10) rotate(55 55 55)" x="25" y="20" fill="white" font-size="10px" pointer-events="none">python</text> 
            <text  x="75" y="85" fill="white" font-size="14px" pointer-events="none">JS</text>      
         <text  x="43" y="95" fill="white" font-size="12px" pointer-events="none">SVG</text>    
       <text  x="18" y="85" fill="white" font-size="12px" pointer-events="none">CSS</text>   
      <text  x="12" y="60" fill="white" font-size="12px" pointer-events="none">java</text>    
     <text  x="80" y="60" fill="white" font-size="12px" pointer-events="none">All</text>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант SVG:

```css
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0;}
.g1, .g2, .g3 {fill: goldenrod;}
.o1, .o2, .o3 {fill: orangered;}
svg a:hover .g1, svg a:hover .g2, svg a:hover .g3 {fill: gold;}
svg a:hover .o1, svg a:hover .o2, svg a:hover .o3 {fill: red;}
svg a:hover text {fill: white;}
svg path, svg text {transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;}
```

```html
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500px" height="500px">

<!-- 1 ряд -->

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g1" d="M250,129.5c-33.2,0-63.2,13.5-84.9,35.3l84.9,84.9V129.5z"/>
<text transform="translate(220, 185) rotate(-25)">1</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o1" d="M250,129.5v120.2l84.9-84.9C313.2,142.9,283.2,129.5,250,129.5z"/>
<text transform="translate(275, 180) rotate(25)">2</text>       
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g1" d="M370.1,249.7c0-33.2-13.4-63.2-35.1-84.9L250,249.7H370.1z"/>
<text transform="translate(310, 220) rotate(70)">3</text>       
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o1" d="M334.9,334.6c21.7-21.7,35.1-51.8,35.1-84.9H250L334.9,334.6z"/>
<text transform="translate(310, 270) rotate(120)">4</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g1" d="M250,369.9c33.2,0,63.2-13.5,84.9-35.3L250,249.7V369.9z"/>
<text transform="translate(275, 310) rotate(155)">5</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o1" d="M165.1,334.6c21.7,21.8,51.8,35.3,84.9,35.3V249.7L165.1,334.6z"/>
<text transform="translate(230, 315) rotate(-155)">6</text>     
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g1" d="M129.9,249.7c0,33.2,13.4,63.2,35.1,84.9l84.9-84.9H129.9z"/>
<text transform="translate(185, 280) rotate(-120)">7</text>     
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o1" d="M165.1,164.7c-21.7,21.7-35.1,51.8-35.1,84.9H250L165.1,164.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(175, 225) rotate(-70)">8</text>      
</a></g>

<!-- 2 ряд -->

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o2" d="M250,129.5V58.6c-52.7,0-100.5,21.4-135,56l50.1,50.1C186.8,142.9,216.8,129.5,250,129.5z"/>
<text transform="translate(180, 120) rotate(-25)">2 - 1</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g2" d="M334.9,164.7l50.1-50.1c-34.5-34.6-82.3-56-135-56v70.8C283.2,129.5,313.2,142.9,334.9,164.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(295, 105) rotate(25)">2 - 2</text>       
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o2" d="M334.9,164.7c21.7,21.7,35.1,51.8,35.1,84.9h70.7c0-52.7-21.3-100.4-55.8-135L334.9,164.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(380, 175) rotate(70)">2 - 3</text>       
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g2" d="M334.9,334.6l50.1,50.1c34.5-34.6,55.8-82.3,55.8-135h-70.7C370.1,282.8,356.6,312.9,334.9,334.6z"/>
<text transform="translate(395, 295) rotate(120)">2 - 4</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o2" d="M250,369.9v70.8c52.7,0,100.5-21.4,135-56l-50.1-50.1C313.2,356.4,283.2,369.9,250,369.9z"/>
<text transform="translate(320, 380) rotate(155)">2 - 5</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g2" d="M165.1,334.6L115,384.7c34.5,34.6,82.3,56,135,56v-70.8C216.8,369.9,186.8,356.4,165.1,334.6z"/>
<text transform="translate(205, 390) rotate(-155)">2 - 6</text>     
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o2" d="M129.9,249.7H59.2c0,52.7,21.3,100.4,55.8,135l50.1-50.1C143.4,312.9,129.9,282.8,129.9,249.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(120, 320) rotate(-120)">2 - 7</text>     
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g2" d="M165.1,164.7L115,114.7c-34.5,34.6-55.8,82.3-55.8,135h70.7C129.9,216.5,143.4,186.5,165.1,164.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(110, 210) rotate(-70)">2 - 8</text>      
</a></g>

<!-- 3 ряд -->

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g3" d="M250,58.6V6C182.7,6,121.8,33.3,77.8,77.4l37.2,37.2C149.5,80,197.3,58.6,250,58.6z"/>
<text transform="translate(150, 60) rotate(-25)">3 - 1</text>       
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o3" d="M385,114.7l37.2-37.2C378.2,33.3,317.3,6,250,6v52.7C302.7,58.6,350.5,80,385,114.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(320, 50) rotate(25)">3 - 2</text>
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g3" d="M440.8,249.7h52.6c0-67.2-27.2-128.1-71.2-172.2L385,114.7C419.5,149.2,440.8,197,440.8,249.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(440, 150) rotate(70)">3 - 3</text>       
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o3" d="M440.8,249.7c0,52.7-21.3,100.4-55.8,135l37.2,37.2c44-44.1,71.2-105,71.2-172.2H440.8z"/>
<text transform="translate(450, 320) rotate(120)">3 - 4</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g3" d="M250,440.7v52.7c67.3,0,128.2-27.3,172.2-71.5L385,384.7C350.5,419.3,302.7,440.7,250,440.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(345, 440) rotate(155)">3 - 5</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o3" class="o1" d="M115,384.7l-37.2,37.2c44.1,44.2,105,71.5,172.2,71.5v-52.7C197.3,440.7,149.5,419.3,115,384.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(180, 450) rotate(-155)">3 - 6</text>     
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="g3" d="M59.2,249.7H6.6c0,67.2,27.2,128.1,71.2,172.2l37.2-37.2C80.5,350.1,59.2,302.4,59.2,249.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(60, 350) rotate(-120)">3 - 7</text>      
</a></g>

<g><a href="#">
<path class="o3" d="M115,114.7L77.8,77.4c-44,44.1-71.2,105-71.2,172.2h52.6C59.2,197,80.5,149.2,115,114.7z"/>
<text transform="translate(45, 185) rotate(-70)">3 - 8</text>       
</a></g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Почти дартс) (+)